# Is there any way store the data permanently without database in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, database

Is there any way to store the data without using the database?

Answer (score 1):

Not really no. You could use the localStorage/SessionStorage or IndexedDB for example. But all of these things can be cleared by the user.

Also when he is using an incognito session, the data will also be wiped when he closes the browser.